# xdmp.spawn in marklogic javascript

Tags: javascript, marklogic, spawn

While doing xdmp.spawn function in marklogic as below :

```
var abc = "foo"
xdmp.spawn("/oneplusone.sjs", (xs.QName("abc"), "foo").Object,{result: true})
```

Error :

```
 [javascript] JS-JAVASCRIPT: fn.count(Sequence()) -- Error running JavaScript request: ReferenceError: abc is not defined
```

oneplusone.sjs is a module in my modules database which just returns the value of variable "abc" (which is the string "foo" passing as external)

Can you please help in resolving this issue? Also please give a detailed example of how xdmp.spawn can be used with how the second argument can be passed as an Object.

Comment: Did you try `xdmp.spawn("/oneplusone.sjs", { "abc": "foo" }, {result: true})` yet?

Comment: yes tried.. thanks :) it works perfect :)

Comment: I'll provide a proper answer with that hint..

Answer (score 0):

the below snippet of code works :

```
var name = (xs.QName("abc"), "foo")
xdmp.spawn("/oneplusone.sjs", name.Object,{result: true})
```

The issue was the module which is getting called (/oneplusone.sjs) just had one line of code which is the variable abc.
This works with Xquery but in Javascript they are expecting to declare the variable in the module getting called. Also please let help me in getting the value of the variavle in the module getting called, since now it is being passed as an object

Answer (score 0):

The function is expecting a JSON object with keys referring to the variable names. Invoking namespaced variables in XQuery code is a little more challenging, but that does not apply to Server-side JavaScript. For that you can just do something like this:

```
var abc = "foo"
xdmp.spawn("/oneplusone.sjs", { "abc": abc }, {result: true})
```

In case you want to invoke XQuery code after all, you'll likely need [xdmp.keyFromQName](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.keyFromQName).

HTH!

Comment: This method is to use a single parameter. How would I pass multiple parameters?
I've tried passing it as a JSON array like this 
[ { "abc": abc } , { "def": def } ]
 and also like this:
[ { "abc": abc, "def": def } ] but none of these 2 methods worked @grtjn

Comment: @Mehul, don't pass in an array, but just a single JSON object with multiple keys. So like your second approach, but without the square brackets.

Comment: I instead passed it like this: {v1, v2.. vn}